# How to add multiple email id validation using Jquery or javascript with separated by “;” “,” in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

NOTE:

Same email id can't be repeated.

The empty string value can be allowed to add.

Email Id should separated by ; and ,.

Basic emailId validation is required for entered email id

[![

```js
$("#d-notification").focusout(function () {
    var conditions = [".com", ".in", "@"];
    var d = document.getElementById("d-notification").value;
    var res = conditions.some(el => d.includes(el));
    if (d !== "" && res === false) {
        document.getElementById("error-d").style.display = "block";
        $("#generate-dispatcher").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("error-d").style.display = "none";
        $("#generate-dispatcher").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

```css
#error-d {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <textarea type="text" id="d-notification" class="form__field resize"
   placeholder="Enter the Email Id"></textarea>
 <span id="error-d" class="error-noti">Please Enter valid Email Id</span>
</div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCgSk.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCgSk.png)

Comment: What issue are you facing and where are you stuck? Please explain your issues with some examples to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two choices.
One could be that you set up a control that is a div with a textarea and when you enter an email and then a ";" or a "," it creates a new tag with javascript that can be a div or a span that shows the email to separate it into different items and then validate each of them.
The other could be that when you do the validation as you do now, you make a split of emails by ";" or "," and then validate each email in that array of result.

Good luck
Matias Creimerman